# Simple AngularJS dynamic bar chart

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create a very simple dynamic bar chart using AngularJS 1. I keep getting an error which I think is to do with Angular loading the DOM before the chart is rendered:

```
Cannot read property 'offsetWidth' of null
```

Original Code: https://codepen.io/tomesch/pen/itjqk?editors=0010#0

**Controller**:

```
var values = [85,95,120,100,200,200,230,230,60,320,23,3433,434,45,23,23];

$scope.drawChart = function (data,selector,padding){
    var max = Math.max.apply(Math, data);
    var chart = document.querySelector(selector);
    var barwidth = ((chart.offsetWidth-(values.length-1)*padding-(data.length)*10)/data.length);
    var sum = data.reduce(function(pv, cv) { return pv + cv; }, 0);
    var left = 0;
    for (var i in data){
      var newbar = document.createElement('div');
      newbar.setAttribute("class", "bar");
      newbar.style.width=barwidth+"px";
      newbar.style.height=((data[i]/max)*100)+"%";
      newbar.style.left=left+"px";
      chart.appendChild(newbar);
      left += (barwidth+padding+10);
    }
}

$scope.drawChart(values,"#chartxx",5) // You can adjust the margin between each bar by changing 10 to whatever you like
```

**HTML**

```
  <div class="wrapperx2">
    <div id="chartxx"></div>  
  </div>
```

Comment: Why `window.document.querySelector(selector);` instead of `document.querySelector(selector);` ?

Comment: Tried that and gives same error

Comment: I added window. as I thought it might work since I am using Ionic framework and wanted to check if jquery was available. Just ignore that, have removed from above, but outputs same error with document.querySelector(selector);

Comment: @drew, I get no error in the console and the code renders the chart using both the original code https://jsfiddle.net/f9eopqao/1/ and the code you've provided https://jsfiddle.net/f9eopqao/, BTW you should write a directive to manipulate the DOM and it shouldn't be done in the controller, which version of AngularJS 1.x are you using?